# Openmeetings Add user/group with script

Tags: mysql, user-registration, openmeetings

I'm playing around with openmeetings and was wondering if anyone knows how to write a script to automatically add a user or group.  The idea is that I want to integrate it with a site so that any time a user registers on the site, they automatically receive an openmeetings account and are enrolled in a group.

I figure as a last ditch, I can roll up my sleaves and figure out how to manually edit the appropriate tables but I was wondering if there was either a documented way to accomplish this or a feature built into the openmeetings software for this purpose.

Thanks in advance; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are SOAP and REST APIs [1] to add a user. They can be easily extended to add a group.

[1] http://openmeetings.apache.org/SoapRestAPI.html

Comment: Actually just found it!  It was exactly what I was looking for.  Much Obliged!